# Trouble getting Python to chose the correct code path

Tags: python

I was trying to create a guessing game in Python, and it keeps on printing out the `else:` part even if I typed in the right number (1). What did I do wrong?

```py
print("Pick a number from one to 10 ")
guess = input("Type a number")
num = 1
if guess == 1:
    print("GoodJob actual wizard.")
else:
    print("Try again")
```

Comment: Well, even it is a low-quality question, you could link where in the docs he could find what he was looking for. Send him "read the docs" isn't of big help either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never specify what type `guess` is, you need to convert it to an `int` otherwise comparing it to any integer will be `False`.

Replace:

```
guess = input("Type a number")
```

With:

```
guess = int(input("Type a number"))
```

Answer (score 2):

It happens that the input the user will put on your program is actually a string ("1"), which is different from the integer 1. Just switch

```
guess = input("Type a number")
```

to

```
guess = int(input("Type a number"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Just convert guess variable to an integer and it will perfectly fine for you

```
guess = input("Type a number")
guess = int(guess)
```